# wp_query posts sorting doesn't work

Tags: posts, wp-query, filters

I am trying to add a front end sorting to the posts by default in most recent and adding two link options 1: **Sort by Title** 2: **Sort by Date**. However, my problem is that for me it's not working. I tried searching for answers on here and on Google and found [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/209099/front-end-sorting-questions) very similar fix which i am trying to follow but it isn't working for me. I have been trying for a long time but it just doesn't want to work for me.

Please see the code that I'm working with:

```
<?php
$args= [
'category_name' => get_queried_object()->post_name,
'order'         => 'DESC',
'orderby'       => 'date'
];

if( isset( $_GET['sort'] ) && "date" == $_GET['sort'] ){
$args['orderby'] = 'date';
}

$A = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $A->have_posts() ) {
$A->the_post();
echo '<li>' .get_the_title() .'</li>';
}

wp_reset_postdata(); /*instead of wp_reset_query?*/

/* 2nd Query Sort? */
$args2= [
'category_name' => 'Uncategorized',
'order'         => 'ASC',
'orderby'       => 'title'
];

if( isset( $_GET['sort'] ) && "title" == $_GET['sort'] ){
$args['orderby'] = 'title';
}

$B = new WP_Query($args2);

// Loop 2?
while( $B->have_posts()) {
$B->the_post();
echo '<li>' .get_the_title() .'</li>';
}

//Restoring original post data
wp_reset_postdata();
?>

<a href="?sort=title">Sort By Title</a>
<a href="?sort=date">Sort By Date</a>

<?php query_posts($order.'&order=DESC');  ?>
```

I am trying to add 'Sort by Title' link in ASC order and 'Sort by Date' in DESC order as in Most Recent order.

Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you're dealing with the main query then you can just put `?orderby=title` in the URL and it will work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but sorry it didn't work: `<a href="?orderby=title">Sort By Title</a>` Is there a way to get this to work please? I have been onit for hours trying to fix it =/

Answer (score -1):

Thank you, Jacob your suggestion put me into the right direction.

This resolved the issue:

```
<a href="?orderby=title&order=ASC">Sort By Title</a>
<a href="?orderby=date&order=DESC">Sort By Date</a>
```

How can I upvote or add +rep you on here? thanks again bro :)

Comment: why -1 me for? that's a legit answer thought might help out someone.